# DefaultMessageListenerContainer per JmsListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

Am building a application which need to have high performance JMS processing. It will read messages from queue and after processing, the same message will be published to another queue.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "queue1", containerFactory = "containerFactory", concurrency = "16-32")

@JmsListener(destination = "queue2", containerFactory = "containerFactoryExt", concurrency = "16-32")

@JmsListener(destination = "queue3", containerFactory = "containerFactory2", concurrency = "16-32")

@JmsListener(destination = "queue4", containerFactory = "containerFactoryExt2", concurrency = "16-32")
```

Here is code where i create the Container factory.

```
@Bean(name = "containerFactory")
public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws NamingException {
    //call to createJmsListenerContainerFactory()
}


@Bean(name = "containerFactoryExt")
public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws NamingException {
    //call to createJmsListenerContainerFactory()
}

@Bean(name = "containerFactory2")
public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws NamingException {
    //call to createJmsListenerContainerFactory()
}

@Bean(name = "containerFactoryExt2")
public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws NamingException {
    //call to createJmsListenerContainerFactory()
}


 JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> createJmsListenerContainerFactory(
        ConnectionFactory cf,DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, cf);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setConcurrency("15-50");
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(2);
    factory.setBackOff(new FixedBackOff());
    return factory;
}
```

Is it recommened to have separate container factory per listener? any other suggestion to improve the performance?

Comment: No it isn't. The `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` is a factory which will create an `DefaultJmsListenerContainer` for each listener. So having a factory for each doesn't mak sense.

Comment: Thanks. Is this concurrency setting in  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory  per listener or global? Is there max limit on currency i can set?

Comment: As stated, it is a factory to create listener containers. The configuration set on the factory is used (read copied) to the listener container and acts as a default. The concurrency per listener can be given in the annotations.

Comment: Thanks for you time. So what does  factory.setConcurrency("15-50"); mean then if we are allowed to set the concurrency on listeners?

Comment: It will be used as a default if you don't provide a concurrency (as I mentioned in my previous comment).